# Ipython : Installation error, unable to find _sqlite.so

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, ipython

On trying to install ipython for Python3.4 I get a message that it is already installed.

```
pip3 install ipython
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
```

But when I try to run it with `ipython3 notebook` I get all this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython3", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(start_ipython())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 120, in start_ipython
return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 573, in launch_instance
app.initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 321, in initialize
super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 369, in initialize
self.parse_command_line(argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 316, in parse_command_line
return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in parse_command_line
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 471, in parse_command_line
return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)
  File "<string>", line 2, in initialize_subcommand
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 75, in catch_config_error
return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py", line 402, in initialize_subcommand
subapp = import_item(subapp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/utils/importstring.py", line 42, in import_item
module = __import__(package, fromlist=[obj])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/notebookapp.py", line 67, in <module>
from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/IPython/html/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 7, in <module>
import sqlite3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'
```

Assuming that the last line is the most important

`ImportError: No module named '_sqlite3'`

I tried to install all sorts of dependencies for it:

`apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev`

When I tried installing Pysqlite via `pip3 install pysqlite` :

```
Collecting pysqlite
  Using cached pysqlite-2.6.3.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-ggtq7_wu/pysqlite/setup.py", line 85
        print "Is sphinx installed? If not, try 'sudo easy_install sphinx'."
                                                                       ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ggtq7_wu/pysqlite
```

However Sphinx is already installed. I even reinstalled it.

```
pip3 install sphinx
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sphinx in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Jinja2>=2.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): snowballstemmer>=1.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils>=0.11 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): babel>=1.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): sphinx-rtd-theme<0.2,>=0.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): alabaster<0.8,>=0.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Pygments>=2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.4 in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): markupsafe in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.3->sphinx)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=0a in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from babel>=1.3->sphinx)
```

Hence I have not been able to resolve it because evidently that file `_sqlite3.so` which should be in `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload` does not exist and I cannot find a way to install it.

Comment: try `pip3 install -U ipython`

Comment: Requirement already up-to-date: ipython in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages

Comment: try `sudo pip3 install -U  --force-reinstall ipython`

Comment: You seem to have a botched python - who created a python in `/usr/local`? And why is `sqlite3` not installed? That's the actual question - ipython just happens to try & and use that, nothing in it's installation is wrong.

Comment: "SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'" This is a typical error you get when running python2 code in a python3 environment. The packages you are trying to install is obviously not meant for python3.

Comment: It looks like at some point you've compiled your own Python, and it doesn't have sqlite bindings. You should either remove that and use the system Python 3, or recompile it with `libsqlite3-dev` installed (if it's missing when you compile Python, Python skips building the sqlite bindings).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to resolve it thanks to the help I got in the comments.
Just putting it here to make it easy for anyone else who may have the same issue to figure out whats going on.

The issue is in using a self compiled version of Python, before the sql dev files were installed. Hence the bindings did not take.

First I had to use `sudo apt-get install sqlite3 libsqlite3-dev` to get the relevant sqlite files.

Then I had to recompile the Python by using a Source Tarball and executing the following commands to recompile it.

```
make clean
./configure 
make 
make install
```

Answer (score -1):

I got the same issue on CentOS 6.8 and I installed `sqlite-devel` and then I re-compiled the python and got the issue fixed:

```
yum install sqlite-devel
```